# Plotting Raster Above a shapefile

Tags: python, rasterio, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a raster above a shapefile in python.  My code is working however I can't seem to get the raster to plot above the shapefiles.  It only appears when I don't show countries, rivers or PAA.

Is there a way I can plot the raster above my shapefiles?  Here's my code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show


#### loading in shp & raster #####
extent = gpd.read_file("/Users/humzahqazilbash/Desktop/temporary/extents/extent.shp")
countries = gpd.read_file("/Users/humzahqazilbash/Desktop/temporary/COUNTRIES.shp")
rivers = gpd.read_file("/Users/humzahqazilbash/Downloads/useful data/Natural Earth/ne_10m_rivers_lake_centerlines/ne_10m_rivers_lake_centerlines.shp")
PAA = gpd.read_file("/Users/humzahqazilbash/Documents/PA.shp")

change_2020 = rasterio.open("/Users/humzahqazilbash/Desktop/Change.tif")



fig,ax = plt.subplots()


xlim = ([extent.total_bounds[0],  extent.total_bounds[2]])
ylim = ([extent.total_bounds[1],  extent.total_bounds[3]])

ax.set_xlim(xlim)
ax.set_ylim(ylim)
ax.set_axis_off();  #AXIS OFF#


rasterio.plot.show( 
  change_2020,
  ax=ax,
 cmap = 'Reds',
 alpha = 1  
)

countries.plot(
  ax = ax,
  color = '#F0F0F0',
  alpha = 1
)

PAA.plot(
  ax = ax,
  color = '#78de89',
  alpha=1
)

rivers.plot(
  ax=ax,
  color= '#acf6fa',
  linewidth = 0.5
)


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

FIXED: fixed this issue using zorder within rasterio.plot.show()